# OpenGL GLX extension not supported by display when starting Steam (CS:S)

Tags: linux-mint, nvidia-graphics-card, opengl, steam

On my Linux Mint machine I can't get Counter-Strike Source started with my nVidia GeForce GT645M card. 
I installed bumblebee drivers and in NVIDIA X Server Configuration the nVidia card is selected.

What can be the problem?

Comment: And if I do this: sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx, I can't select my nVidia card in NVIDIA X Server Configuration anymore.

Comment: With this level of information none can tell what the problem is. Do you get an error message?